# I need help in my C++ ATM machine code, about filtering out characters or strings

Tags: c++, string, filter, character

I would really not ask if I really know the answer. New to c++ and all I know is here, it's also in Trial and error situation but trying to beat the deadlines, This is a homework. The problem I am encountering now is when a user inputs a char or string, I can't seem to find the solution to filter it out and prompt to "key in again due to invalid input." .. Any ideas? the char seems to value on 0. Tried to key in conditions regarding to that but still not working. Don't know what to do with this.

```
#include <iostream>
#include <conio.h>
using namespace std;

/*--------------------------------------------------
---------------------------------------------------------
Accounts are under pinnumbers:                           |
1001 increment of 1                                      |
Passcodes are under the codes:                           |
1101 increment of 1                                      |
                                                         |
limit of 10 as instructed.                               |
                                                         |
i.e : (valid pin number ) 1001 = (valid pin code) 1101   |
---------------------------------------------------------
*/

int option, pinnumber, pincode, vip[10], pc[10], money[10], accountno[10], getindex;
string name[10]; 
void mainmenu();
void assignaccounts();
void checkaccounts();
void start();
void options();
bool logged=false;
char a,b,c,d,e,f,g,h,i,j,k,l,m,n,o,p,q,r,s,t,u,v,w,x,y,z;


//<--START OF THE MAIN FUNCTION -->
main() {       

assignaccounts();
start();                      
system("PAUSE"); //more of a getch() pero naa xa'y press any key. w/c is better!
}

//<--EOF MAIN FUNCTION-->

//<-- START OF EXTRA FUNCTION SECTION --> 
//---Start of checkaccounts function --> -----------------------------
void checkaccounts() {                                              //|
        for(int x=0; x<10; x++) {                                   //|
          if(( vip[x] == pinnumber)  && ( pc[x] == pincode  )) {    //|
            logged=true;                                            //|
            getindex=x;                                             //|
            mainmenu();                                             //|
            break;                                                  //|
         } else if ((pinnumber == 'a') && (pincode == 'A' )) {
           cout<<"Invalid Input, Try again."<<endl;
           cin.clear();
           main();
           break;   
         } else {
           ;
         }                                                         //|                                                        
        }                                                           //|
        if(!logged){                                                //|
               cout<<"\n\t Invalid Input, Try again."<<"\n\n\t ";   //|
               system("PAUSE");                                     //|
               start();                                             //|
        }                                                           //|
                                                                    //|                                                                   
}                                                                   //|
//end of checkaccounts function --------------------------------------


//Start of Assignaccounts function------------------------------------
void assignaccounts() {                                             //|
       for(int x=0; x<10; x++) {                                    //|
         vip[x]=1001+x;                                             //|
         pc[x]=1101+x;                                              //|                                                         
        }                                                           //|
   name[0] = "John Do Doe";                                         //|
   money[0] = 10000;                                                //|
   accountno[0] = 1;                                                //|
                                                                    //|
   name[1] = "Zsaza Pa Ligid";                                      //|
   money[1] = 20000;                                                //|
   accountno[1] = 2;                                                //|
                                                                    //|
   name[2] = "Robin Pa Didit";                                      //|
   money[2] = 30000;                                                //|
   accountno[2] = 3;                                                //|
                                                                    //|
   name[3] = "lrem ipm";                                            //|
   money[3] = 40000;                                                //|
   accountno[3] = 4;                                                //|
                                                                    //|
   name[4] = "Daniel Pa Slide";                                     //|
   money[4] = 50000;                                                //|
   accountno[4] = 5;                                                //|
                                                                    //|
   name[5] = "James Bond";                                          //|
   money[5] = 60000;                                                //|
   accountno[5] = 6;                                                //|
                                                                    //|
   name[6] = "Lara Croft Llara";                                    //|
   money[6] = 70000;                                                //|
   accountno[6] = 7;                                                //|
                                                                    //|                                                                 
   name[7] = "John Ziggy Pa ( GOLD MEMBER )";                       //|
   money[7] = 90000;                                                //|
   accountno[7] = 11;                                               //|
                                                                    //|
   name[8] = "Loren Joy Chris ( GOLD MEMBER )";                     //|
   money[8] = 110000;                                               //|
   accountno[8] = 10;                                               //|
                                                                    //|
   name[9] = "Jayson Derulo";                                       //|
   money[9] = 120000;                                               //|
   accountno[9] = 10;                                               //|
                                                                    //|
}                                                                   //|
//End of Assignaccounts function--------------------------------------


//---Start of start function --> -------------------------------------
void start() {                                                      //|           
     system("cls");                                                 //|
     cin.clear();
     cout<<"------------------------------------------"<<endl;      //|
     cout<<" |** WELCOME TO CAMARILLO & ALJON ATM **|"<<endl;       //|
     cout<<"------------------------------------------"<<endl;      //|
     cout<<"\nEnter valid identification pin number (VIP): ";       //|
     cin>>pinnumber;                                                //|
     cout<<"\nEnter valid pincode (PC): ";                          //|
     cin>>pincode;                                                  //|
     checkaccounts();                                               //|
                                                                    //|
}                                                                   //|
//end of Start function ----------------------------------------------


//start of mainmenu function ----------------------------------------------------------------------------------
void mainmenu() {                                                                                           // |
     int choice;                                                                                            // |
     if(logged) {                                                                                           // |
      while(true){                                                                                          // |
         system("cls"); //clearscreen                                                                       // |
         cout<<"Log-in successful!"<<endl;                                                                  // |
         cout<<"\nWelcome: "<<name[getindex];                                                                // |
         cout<<"\nAccount No.: "<<accountno[getindex]<<endl;
         cout<<"\nChoose a Transaction:\n";                                                                 // |
         cout<<"\n";                                                                                        // |
         cout<<"[1] Inquire Balance \n"                                                                     // |
         <<"[2] Withdraw \n"                                                                                // |
         <<"[3] Deposit \n"                                                                                 // |
         <<"[4] Quit \n"                                                                                    // |
         <<"\n"<<endl;                                                                                      // |
         cout<<"Enter Option: ";                                                                            // |
         cin>>option;                                                                                       // |
                                                                                                            // |
          if (option == 1) {                                                                                // |
            cout<<"\n\tOutstanding Balance is P"<<money[getindex]<<"\n\n\t ";                               // |
            system("PAUSE");                                                                                // |
         } else if (option == 2) {                                                                          // |
           int co;                                                                                          // |
           cout<<"\n\tEnter amount: ";                                                                      // |
                 cin>>co;                                                                                   // |
                 if(co<money[getindex]){                                                                    // |
                    money[getindex]-=co;                                                                    // |
                    cout<<"\n\tYour Outstanding Balance has been updated to P"<<money[getindex]<<"\n\n\t "; // |
                 } else {                                                                                   // |
                    cout<<"\n\t Invalid amount, Please check again.";                                       // |
                    cout<<"\n\t You only have P"<<money[getindex]<<" in your account."<<"\n\n\t ";          // |
                 }                                                                                          // |
                 system("PAUSE");                                                                           // |
         } else if (option == 3) {                                                                          // |
           int dep; //Declaration of the cin in this case;                                                  // |
                 cout<<"\n\tEnter amount: ";                                                                // |
                 cin>>dep;                                                                                  // |
                 money[getindex]+=dep;                                                                      // |
                 cout<<"\n\tYour Outstanding Balance has been updated to P"<<money[getindex]<<"\n\n\t ";    // |
                 system("PAUSE");                                                                           // |
         } else if (option == 4) {                                                                          // |
           break;                                                                                           // |
         } else{                                                                                            // |
               cout << "\n\n\tInvalid Input, Try again.\n\n\t ";                                            // |
               system("PAUSE");                                                                             // |
         }                                                                                                  // |
      }                                                                                                     // |
         cout<<"\n\n\t THANK YOU FOR USING OUR ATM, YOU'LL NOW EXIT THE PROGRAM."<<endl;                    // |
         cout<<"\n\t This is intended for our project in c++ under Professor Machica."<<"\n\n\t ";          // |                                                 
     }                                                                                                      // |                                                                                                          // |
}                                                                                                           // |
//end of mainmenu function-------------------------------------------------------------------------------------

//<-- EOF EXTRA SECTION FUNCTIONS-->
```

Comment: Just out of curiosity, why do you have all those *insane* comments wrapped around functions? Do you think that a comment like "*Start of start function -->*" helps in *any* way?

Comment: Nope, That's a guide for my partner.. I should have quoted ignore comments. well it's nothing really, if It bugs your eyes just clear it in your brain. sorry for the nasty comments though.
"We're new" still studying.

Answer (score 0):

You can check if cin is not getting the right type using    if(cin.fail()) or   if(!cin)

```
int n;
cin >> n;
if(!cin)
{
     // user didn't input a number
}else{
     // user did input number
}
```

if the input is not an int it will set the failbit flag.

- cin.fail() Checks whether either failbit or badbit is set.
- cin.bad()  Checks whether badbit is set
- cin.eof()  Checks whether eofbit is set

if cin is failing you should use cin.ignore() to ignore the input and ask the user te retry.

NOTE: main() should return an int not void.

This program runs 'input:' and if its not an int it will loop.

```
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;
int main(int argc, const char * argv[])
{
    int ival;
input:
    if(cin >> ival)
    {

        cout << ival << endl;
        // do something (input is a number)
    }
    if(!cin >> ival)
    {
        cin.clear();
        cin.ignore();
        cout << "error, retry" << endl;
        goto input;

    }
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: What if user inputs numbers within the menu followed with a char.
would this check fix this?

Comment: If a user would enter something like "123abc" it will fail because thats not an int.

Comment: Pardon me but I don't quite get it. It will cause my program to Run infinitely.. Will you give a concrete example? like program will ask
"enter 1st integer: "
"enter 2nd integer: "
if the user inputs on the 1st integer a char or string or mixed.
it will prompt to do it again. the program will not exit but go back to asking. I tried to do this but I think I need an example.

Comment: that code of yours doesn't do anything, it will not prompt retry.. It will exit the program.

Comment: wait a minute ill take a look at it again :S

Answer (score 0):

firstly,I think your code should use structed array to store those information.And as a beginner in C ,you should also try not to make variable Public,instead,you should use them as an argument.And it seems like you also don't know char strings,you should use `strcmp` to compare your strings to get interact with your user.I'm just sharing some thought here,maybe u should first learn some knowledge about C strings,struct,structed array and pointer first.

Comment: Yes. I am new with this that's why I have that kind of style. Sorry.
But I think that does not answer my troubles with the user input.
i.e if the user inputs chars which is not on the menu, also if the user inputs the number in the menu but yet followed by a char, I want this things filtered out.

Answer (score 0):

Use this code to force the user to input an `int`.

```
int value;
std::cout << "Enter a number: ";
for (std::string input; std::getline(std::cin, input);) { // Read all characters.
    std::istringstream iss(input);
    if (iss >> value && iss.eof()) { // Try to parse to int.
        break;
    }
    std::cout << "Invalid number, try again: ";
}

std::cout << "Number was: " << value << std::endl;
```

Remember to include:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <sstream>
#include <string>
```

Comment: Snipe, sorry.. but will you please talk to me as if I were a baby? I am very new to this c++, The code you've seen above were basically constructed experimentally with the help of internet and I'm trying to understand it fully. For me to explain myself. considering that help of yours, what is that "std::" there's no declaration of it either..

Comment: @ShaLala The `::` is called a scope resolution operator and `std` is a namespace. If you don't know these concepts I suggest reading a beginners book about C++ programming or at least look through an online tutorial like: http://www.cprogramming.com/tutorial.html or http://www.cplusplus.com/doc/tutorial/.

Comment: @ShaLala The code uses the function `getline` (included from `<string>`) to read all characters from input until an end of line character is found (i.e. linefeed or carriage return). Then it uses an input `stringstream` object/stream to try to parse the characters into an integer number. This is done repeatedly until success and end of the stream is reached (all characters were parsed).